# 5 card poker hand double counting cards

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, poker

This equation calculates the number of ways to get a pair in a 5 card poke hand.
How come this equation doesn't need to be divided by two? My rational for dividing by 2 is as follows:
The first two operations calculate getting a pair, and the second two operations calculate getting the other 3 cards in a five card hands. But doesn't multiplying these together imply that order matters. So doesn't it inherently double your answer, because it assumes that pair,other,other,other, is different from other,other,other,pair.

$${13 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}{12 \choose 3}{(4^3)}$$

Could someone please help me understand this. Thanks.

Comment: Because combination is number of ways (not unique) from the core.  (4/2) = 6 not 4*3.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as follows: Multiplying the number of different possibilities for a pair `A A` and for the remaining cards `B C D` (disregarding order among the three, of course) together, gives you the number of combinations for hands of the form `A A B C D`, where each letter denotes some card and reorderings of `B C D` are not counted seperately. This amounts to disregarding order altogether.

If you were interested in the number of possibilities *where the placement of the pair mattered*, you'd have to multiply your result by the number of different positions that the pair cards can take in your hand (which is $5\choose 2$). Then you'd be counting e.g.  `A B A C D` and `B C D A A` as seperate possibilities.